# How to get rid of these booleans but return a boolean

Tags: java, boolean

I was wondering if anyone could help me to understand how to eliminate the two member booleans from this method:

```
 public boolean testAdd() {

    boolean addPositSuccess;
    boolean addNegatSuccess;

    Double firstPositiveNumber = 22.0;
    Double secondPositiveNumber = 33.0;

    calc.x = firstPositiveNumber;

    if (calc.x(secondPositiveNumber) == (firstPositiveNumber + secondPositiveNumber)) {

        System.out.println("[ OK ] Calculator can add positive numbers");
        addPositSuccess = true;

    } else {

        System.out.println("[FAIL] Calculator adds incorrectly");
        addPositSuccess = false;

    }

    Double firstNegativeNumber = -5.0;
    Double secondNegativeNumber = -6.0;

    calc.x = firstNegativeNumber;
    if (calc.x(secondNegativeNumber) == (firstNegativeNumber + secondNegativeNumber)) {

        System.out.println("[ OK ] Calculator can add a negative number");
        addNegatSuccess = true;

    } else {

        System.out.println("[FAIL] Calculator adds with negative numbers incorrectly");
        addNegatSuccess = false;

    }

    if ((addPositSuccess = true) && (addNegatSuccess = true)) { 
        return true; 
    } else { 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Lets assume calc is just referring to an instance of a stub class.

Comment: Are you sure you should be doing `addPositSuccess = true` within an `if`? What does `=` do?

Comment: `if ((addPositSuccess = true) && (addNegatSuccess = true)) {` doesn't look good (`=` assigns value, `==` compares them). Also `if (conditon) return true; else return false;` can be replaced with `return condition;`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well I'm kinda new to Java so I don't understand what's wrong with that?

Comment: What does `=` do? What does `==` do?

Comment: You'd be reassigning your variables, regardless of what was in them prior.  This would mean your method would always return `true`.

Comment: You could just remove the "= true" and do this: `return addPositSuccess && addNegatSuccess`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well = is just comparing the left and right to see if they are the same and == is comparing to see if their refer to the same variable?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could simply use the Double objects for such purpose. Nonetheless, it's terribly ugly and I really wonder why (and how) you want to eliminate the booleans. Are you sure you are in the right way?

```
public boolean testAdd() {

    Double firstPositiveNumber = 22.0;
    Double secondPositiveNumber = 33.0;

    calc.x = firstPositiveNumber;

    if (calc.x(secondPositiveNumber) == (firstPositiveNumber + secondPositiveNumber)) {

        System.out.println("[ OK ] Calculator can add positive numbers");
        // addPositSuccess = true;

    } else {

        System.out.println("[FAIL] Calculator adds incorrectly");
        firstPositiveNumber = null;

    }

    Double firstNegativeNumber = -5.0;
    Double secondNegativeNumber = -6.0;

    calc.x = firstNegativeNumber;
    if (calc.x(secondNegativeNumber) == (firstNegativeNumber + secondNegativeNumber)) {

        System.out.println("[ OK ] Calculator can add a negative number");
        // addNegatSuccess = true;

    } else {

        System.out.println("[FAIL] Calculator adds with negative numbers incorrectly");
        firstNegativeNumber = null;

    }

    if ((firstPositiveNumber != null) && (firstNegativeNumber != null)) { 
        return true; 
    } else { 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This wasn't what I was looking for but thanks, this is quite a useful way of getting rid of limited use booleans

Answer (score 0):

Any statement within an `if` expression returns a boolean; therefore, instead of writing:

```
if (condition)
    someBoolean = true;
else
    someBoolean = false;
```

you can just write:

```
someBoolean = condition;
```

Apply this to your code and you will drastically shorten it... Exercise left to the OP.

Comment: return ((addPositSuccess) && (addNegatSuccess)); ?

Comment: I was mostly referring to the previous code, but this, of course, will also work since the `testAdd()` method returns a boolean

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public boolean testAdd() {

Double firstPositiveNumber = 22.0;
Double secondPositiveNumber = 33.0;

calc.x = firstPositiveNumber;

if (calc.x(secondPositiveNumber) == (firstPositiveNumber + secondPositiveNumber)) {

    System.out.println("[ OK ] Calculator can add positive numbers");
    return true;

} else {

    System.out.println("[FAIL] Calculator adds incorrectly");
    return false;

}

Double firstNegativeNumber = -5.0;
Double secondNegativeNumber = -6.0;

calc.x = firstNegativeNumber;
if (calc.x(secondNegativeNumber) == (firstNegativeNumber + secondNegativeNumber)) {

    System.out.println("[ OK ] Calculator can add a negative number");
    return true;

} else {

    System.out.println("[FAIL] Calculator adds with negative numbers incorrectly");
    return false;

}


}
```

Comment: Won't work, after the first if statement, you can't have any more code if I implemented that.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your tests are nearly identical. So you would normally factor these in to methods:

```
public boolean testAdd() {
    // note: using & instead of && ensures both methods are called
    return testAddPositive() & testAddNegative();
}

private boolean testAddPositive() {
    return testAdd(22.0, 33.0, "positive");
}

private boolean testAddNegative() {
    return testAdd(-5.0, -6.0, "negative");
}

private boolean testAdd(Double firstNumber, Double secondNumber, String type) {
    calc.x = firstNumber;

    if (calc.x(secondNumber) == (firstNumber + secondNumber)) {
        System.out.println("[ OK ] Calculator can add " + type + " numbers");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("[FAIL] Calculator adds " + type + " incorrectly");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I would normally do that but I have a specification to stick to which means I can't :(

Comment: If you can't do this then it is a silly restriction. This is the sensible way to factor it so if you aren't allowed to do it, I wouldn't worry too much about factoring it sensibly. Your booleans are fine (provided you fix the error that's been pointed out in comments).